# Paypal API error: 10400

Tags: php, paypal

Hello i'm having an issue with the paypal API
so I set everything up for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and now I'm trying to do the DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

Here is the error I've got:

```
array (size=9)
  'TIMESTAMP' => string '2015-10-10T18:56:25Z' (length=20)
  'CORRELATIONID' => string '1ad7e8dba8063' (length=13)
  'ACK' => string 'Failure' (length=7)
  'VERSION' => string '98.0' (length=4)
  'BUILD' => string '18308778' (length=8)
  'L_ERRORCODE0' => string '10400' (length=5)
  'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => string 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.' (length=94)
  'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => string 'Order total is missing.' (length=23)
  'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => string 'Error' (length=5)
```

Here is my code:

My Paypal Class:

```
<?php

class Paypal{

    private $user = 'xxxxxx';
    private $pwd = '5xxxxxx';
    private $signature = 'xxxxxx';
    private $endpoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
    public $errors = array();


    public function __construct($user = false, $pwd = false, $signature = false, $prod = false){
        if($user){
            $this->user = $user;
        }
        if($pwd){
            $this->pwd = $pwd;
        }
        if($signature){
            $this->signature = $signature;
        }
        if($prod){
            $this->endpoint = str_replace('sandbox.','', $this->endpoint);
        }
    }


    public function request($method, $params){
        $params = array_merge($params, array(
            'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
            'VERSION' => '98.0',
            'USER' => $this->user,
            'SIGNATURE' => $this->signature,
            'PWD' => $this->pwd
        ));

        $params = http_build_query($params);
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->endpoint,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1
        ));


        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $responseArray = array();
        parse_str($response, $responseArray);
        if(curl_errno($curl)){
            $this->errors = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close();
            return false;
        }else{
            if($responseArray['ACK'] == 'Success'){
                return $responseArray;
            }else{
                $this->errors = $responseArray;
                curl_close($curl);
                return false;
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Process.php

```
<?php
/*******************
TO DO:
SECURISER l'acces a la page 
$_GET['token'] doit etres defini
$_GET['PayerID'] aussi
*******************/
require 'paypal.php';

$paypal = new Paypal();
$response = $paypal->request('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', array(
    'TOKEN' => $_GET['token']
));

if($response){
}else{
    var_dump($paypal->errors);
    die();
}

$response = $paypal->request('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', array(
    'TOKEN' => $_GET['token'],
    'PAYERID' => $_GET['PayerID'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => $response['PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => $response['PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => 12.0,
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => "Générateur d'énergie quatique",
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0' => 0,
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1' => 2,
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => 30.50,
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => "Hyperdrive T14",
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0' => 1

));

if($response){
    var_dump($response);
}else{
    var_dump($paypal->errors);
}
```

And whenever I get redirected to process.php by paypal after a payment I get this:

```
array (size=9)
  'TIMESTAMP' => string '2015-10-10T18:56:25Z' (length=20)
  'CORRELATIONID' => string '1ad7e8dba8063' (length=13)
  'ACK' => string 'Failure' (length=7)
  'VERSION' => string '98.0' (length=4)
  'BUILD' => string '18308778' (length=8)
  'L_ERRORCODE0' => string '10400' (length=5)
  'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => string 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.' (length=94)
  'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => string 'Order total is missing.' (length=23)
  'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => string 'Error' (length=5)
```

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: **See additional error messages for details** which errors?

Comment: 'L_ERRORCODE0' => string '10400' (length=5)
  'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => string 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.' (length=94)
  'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => string 'Order total is missing.' (length=23)

Answer (score 0):

From the [paypal api error codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/):

```
10400
```

> Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See
>   additional error messages for details.
>
> **OrderTotal is missing**.

Basically, you're missing the `OrderTotal`

Comment: Can you give me the variable that I need to use ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16300565/797495, check the variables he's using, specifically `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=106.72`

Answer (score 0):

Following your code I think the parameter L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 is setted twice with a different prices, check to set only one time